Windows Form with user-selected dynamic control locations/sizes?
I am working on a Windows Form application that uses an embedded VLC player (with Vlc.DotNet.Forms) to display/recall security footage from a few different cameras.
It works well, but right now the controls (Vlc.DotNet.Forms.VlcControl) are in fixed locations for fixed cameras. I want to have a list of all cameras, where the user can choose not only which cameras to view, but their locations and sizes.
Before I go down a rabbit hole of writing a bunch of custom code to allow this, is there any built-in Windows Form or other library that can handle something like this?
At my workplace, we use a camera application that allows the user to select which camera feeds they want to view, as well as locations/sizes of them within a designated area. When you click and drag a camera, the UI shows directional arrows in the current control area to allow the user select where to place the control. See below.

I've seen this exact design in some other applications, e.g. within MS Visual Studio to select window locations.

Since this design seems somewhat common, I thought maybe there is a built-in Windows Form or other standard library for this?

Google for "Winforms Docking Library". All mayor commercial component vendors should have one.

Weifen Luo's DockPanelSuite works like a marvel. You must install the main NuGet package DockPanelSuite and one of the themes. E.g. DockPanelSuite.ThemeVS2012.
